# How to rotate hexagon using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I try rotating the hexagon is based on the edge of it, but it looks weird!

This is my code:

```
$('.hexagon1')
.animate({ // 1
    marginTop:29,
    marginLeft:-50,
    borderSpacing:60
},{
    duration:'slow',
    step:function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+(-now)+'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform-origin','left');
    }
},'linear')
.animate({ // 2
    marginTop:85,
    marginLeft:-50,
    borderSpacing:120
},{
    duration:'slow',
    step:function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+(-now)+'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform-origin','left');
    }
},'linear')
.animate({ // 3
    marginTop:175,
    marginLeft:-100,
    borderSpacing:180
},{
    duration:'slow',
    step:function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+(-now)+'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform-origin','left');
    }
},'linear')
.animate({ // 4
    marginTop:260,
    marginLeft:-50,
    borderSpacing:240
},{
    duration:'slow',
    step:function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+(-now)+'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform-origin','left');
    }
},'linear')
.animate({ // 5
    marginTop:260,
    marginLeft:50,
    borderSpacing:300
},{
    duration:'slow',
    step:function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+(-now)+'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform-origin','left');
    }
},'linear')
.animate({ // 6
    marginTop:175,
    marginLeft:100,
    borderSpacing:360
},{
    duration:'slow',
    step:function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+(-now)+'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform-origin','left');
    }
},'linear');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UserNaN/GvLhR/

If you just take a look at my problem and share a bit of your science, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Please try to define more precisely "it looks weird". We can't know what the expected result would be visually speaking. I think I see what you're talking about, but that's most probably related to imprecisions in calculations...

Comment: I suspect this will be easier to achieve with SVG rather than CSS transforms and background images. Certainly easier because you will be able to reference the actual corners of the hexagon, rather than having CSS guess where there corner should be. I suggest trying something like the Raphael library.